# How to create Augmented Reality Web app using Unity & Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, augmented-reality, vuforia, unity-webgl

I am developing an Augmented Reality app to be integrated into a website using Unity.I need to take output in WebGL. I am using Vuforia to create AR experience. Since Vuforia is not supported with WebGL, i am not able to build. Please suggest an alternate method or how to do Augmented reality in Unity for Web. Is there any alternative to Vuforia?

Answer (score 5):

The good news is yes, you definitely can build an AR experience on the web!

The bad news is that none of the current libraries built for doing so offer a Unity plugin.. Meaning you'll either have to create a wrapper, do some complicated RPC call to talk to the JS library via Unity, or completely scrap Unity altogether and use only the library. To my knowledge, the best browser-based AR library is AR.js. I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but I hope you're able to achieve your goals. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I just took a look at AR.js. Is it possible to have all featues like interaction on an AR model like in Unity to be implemented in AR.js?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. I've never used AR.js, I just knew of its existence. I want to say yes, since it's just a JS framework you should be able to implement a game loop with no problems, but you won't have the helper classes that the Unity API offers, nor will you be able to utilize the power of Mono/.Net. Unless maybe you could somehow import the Unity API into an ASP background application and pass data back and forth, but that would be a team effort at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late in the thread. But I'd like to add an option which might help. You can definitely build your AR app in web using WebGL as output. There is easy way to integrate it with a webiste too. SLAM based AR like Google ARCore is a great example to do it.

There are two options:

1. You can build such an app from scratch which will obviously take more time. Because apart from development, setting up hosting infrastructure is a challenge.
2. Otherwise, if you want to scale such AR web app development with low or no code and cloud ready hosting, you can use a SaaS platform called Marvin XR.

You can login and try it out for FREE: https://www.marvinxr.com:8443

Hope this helps the other folks who stumble upon this thread.